# upload file in Nodejs using s3 npm package

Tags: node.js

I am uploading video file using s3 bucket in Nodejs.

when I upload file on s3 bucket, it is also uploaded in *temp/* folder. So after few video upload temp folder is become full due to this I can not upload more video.

How to remove this video from temp folder after file successfully or not upload on s3 bucket in Nodejs code?

I have used below package for s3 bucket.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

Comment: It's weird, there's no reason the file should be saved to a local directory without an explicit instruction to do so. As a workaround, you can always delete the `temp` folder after an upload

Comment: @JeremyThille I have no code for save file in temp folder

Comment: I think you should try [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)

Comment: @sidgujrathi where I can try this ? I am beginner in nodejs.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Can you share your code? I think the something else, like another module, is creating the temp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.abortMultipartUpload(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // USE BELOW CODE HERE
  else     console.log(data);           // ALSO HERE
});
```

Here is example of how can you remove/delete file from system using NodeJS

```
// include node fs module
var fs = require('fs');

// delete file named 'sample.txt'
fs.unlink('sample.txt', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // if no error, file has been deleted successfully
    console.log('File deleted!');
});
```

Comment: I know how to use this. But where to use it ?

Comment: See my edited answer, look for comment in `IF` and `ELSE` You can use code in that sections. So that if s3 successfully saves file it will delete from system and evenn if s3 fail to do so it will remove the temp file.

Answer (score 0):

```
const multer = require("multer");


require("dotenv").config();

const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

aws.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
});

const BUCKET = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
const s3 = new aws.S3();

// Multer config
module.exports = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    bucket: BUCKET,
    s3: s3,
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    acl: "public-read",

    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
    },
  }),
});
```